# How are IAM Policies taken into account when accessing objects in buckets from Django Server

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Here is my current situation. I have a django server with which I host a website. That server uses Django-Storages and Django-Storages uses, let's say, my Amazon's IAM user called "user1".

Now, let's say I have two buckets: bucket_1 and bucket_2. **My django server needs to use bucket_1 for the static files**. If in my "user1" IAM Policy, I give it the **only** the following:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "s3:*",
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bucket_2",
                 "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_2/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

How come the images are still being properly being shown to my users on my website?

Does that mean that I have to specifically create a bucket policy and say that this bucket is only accessible by **user1**?

I found this from Amazon:

> If you’re more interested in “What can this user do in AWS?” then IAM
>   policies are probably the way to go. You can easily answer this by
>   looking up an IAM user and then examining their IAM policies to see
>   what rights they have.
>
> If you’re more interested in “Who can access this S3 bucket?” then S3
>   bucket policies will likely suit you better. You can easily answer
>   this by looking up a bucket and examining the bucket policy.

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxPOJBY6FE360K/IAM-policies-and-Bucket-Policies-and-ACLs-Oh-My-Controlling-Access-to-S3-Resourc

So does that mean that my policy says "what he can do within the AWS platform", but the bucket, **unless I give it a bucket policy**, is essentially opened to everyone?

Personally, I would have assumed that whenever my "bucket_1" sees the Django request from "user_1", AWS was going to be like "Sorry user_1, you can only access bucket_2".

Answer (score 1):

> Personally, I would have assumed that whenever my "bucket_1" sees the
>   Django request from "user_1", AWS was going to be like "Sorry user_1,
>   you can only access bucket_2".

So this is the correct behavior. So if your user doesn't have have permissions to S3 this is what it would look like on the S3 console. In essence it shouldn't tell you you can only access bucket_2 but it should tell you that you are not able to access bucket_1.

[image: S3 Denied]

I assume you are hosting your django app in an EC2 instance. By any chance have you started it with an IAM role that may have full access to S3. Something like like this:

[image: IAM]

Keep in mind that if you want to restrict access to a bucket for a user and you want it to be able to list the bucket you need to allow the user to list all buckets because of the `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` action limitation.  You policy would look something like this:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "s3:PutBucketAcl",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_2/*",
      "Condition": {}
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: There you go. My EC2 instance doesn't have a IAM role... so is that the problem then?!

Comment: Hmm, should be other way around AFAIK. In any case you may want to play adding a role and then restricting that role.

Comment: What I mean is that... if that instance doesn't have a role, then it can do whatever it wants basically correct? If I give it a role, then whenever it makes requests, it will look at that policy and then it should work?

Comment: What I mean is that if the instance doesn't have any IAM role associated with it, it should not allow you access to anything. If it does have a role then it could allow you some access depending on the policy of that role.

Comment: To chime in shortly - IAM uses _default deny_, i.e. you'll never have permission for anything if you haven't explicitly granted it somehow (that's an appropriate security first approach of course). This also applies to IAM roles, and if there is none, then apps on that instance won't be able to retrieve IAM role credentials in the first place (which is usually handled implicitly by the various SDKs), thus can't access anything, if they don't have other credentials at their disposal. So as [already discussed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22542396/45773), @abisson has a misconfiguration elsewhere.

Comment: This is getting frustrating... I talked with some people regarding the behaviour of Django when requesting objects to S3... and they seem to say that the IAM AccessKey is not directly taken into account when Django makes request for that specific static file. It is Django-Storages that I am using to render the static files.